# KendoUI build a MVVM bound checkbox list

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui

I can't figure this out and it's driving me nuts.

I have the following code (dojo [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/eVOGo))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

 <!-- kendo and jquery references -->

  <script>
    window.onload = function(){
    window.viewModel = window.kendo.observable({
                       userSource: [{id: 1, name: "user1" },
                                    {id: 2, name: "user2" },
                                    {id: 3, name: "user3" }],
                       selectedTeam: {
                            users: []
                            }
                       });

    kendo.bind('#main',viewModel);
    }
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div data-bind="source: userSource, value: selectedTeam" 
         data-template="template">
     <script id="template" type="text/html">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: users"/>#:name#<br/>
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I can't seem to do is bind the checkbox to **selectedTeam.users**

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can't bind it to `selectedTeam.users` as you define it you say that on `click` in the checkbox the system should update a member of the source `userSource` called `users` but this is not what you want, you want to update a different array.

In order to show what I mean run the following snippet. If you initially click on "show" button you get your defined `userSource` but if then you start marking the checkboxes you will see that the `userSource` gets extended with a new field called `users`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {   
  var viewModel = window.kendo.observable({
    userSource: [
      {id: 1, name: "user1" },
      {id: 2, name: "user2" },
      {id: 3, name: "user3" }
    ],
    selectedTeam: {
      users: []
    }
  });

  kendo.bind('#main',viewModel);
  $("#show").on("click", function() {
    alert("userSource :" + JSON.stringify(viewModel.userSource));
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.default.min.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<button id="show">Show</button>
<div id="main">
  <div data-bind="source: userSource, value: selectedTeam" data-template="template">
    <script id="template" type="text/html">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: users"/>#:name#<br/>
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't think that you can do it as you want but you can get a similar result but depends on how you plan to use it.

One possible solution is when you click in one of the checkboxes then update `selectedTeam.users` array. Another is taking advantage of that you are saving in `userSource` the status of the checkbox for implementing a method that each time that you invoke it, it computes the actual array of selected users.

**Approach 1**:

```
window.onload = function(){
    window.viewModel = window.kendo.observable({
        userSource: [
            {id: 1, name: "user1" },
            {id: 2, name: "user2" },
            {id: 3, name: "user3" }
        ],
        selectedTeam: {
            users: []
        },
        updateTeam: function(e) {
            if (e.target.checked) {
                alert("Should add '" + e.data.name + "' to the selectedTeam.users array");
            } else { 
                alert("Should remove '" + e.data.name + "' from the selectedTeam.users array");
            }
        }
    });
    kendo.bind('#main',viewModel);
  }
```

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.viewModel = window.kendo.observable({
    userSource: [
      {id: 1, name: "user1" },
      {id: 2, name: "user2" },
      {id: 3, name: "user3" }],
    selectedTeam: {
      users: []
    },
    updateTeam: function(e) {
      if (e.target.checked) {
        alert("Should add '" + e.data.name + "' to the selectedTeam.users array");
      } else { 
        alert("Should remove '" + e.data.name + "' from the selectedTeam.users array");
      }
    }
  });

  kendo.bind('#main',viewModel);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.default.min.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <div data-bind="source: userSource, value: selectedTeam" data-template="template">
  </div>
</div>

<script id="template" type="text/html">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="events: { click: updateTeam }"/>#:name#
  </div>
</script>
```

**Approach 2**

```
window.onload = function(){
    window.viewModel = window.kendo.observable({
        userSource: [
            {id: 1, name: "user1" },
            {id: 2, name: "user2" },
            {id: 3, name: "user3" }
        ],
        selectedTeam: function() {
            var users = [];
            $.each(this.userSource, function(idx, elem) {
                if (elem.users) users.push(elem.name);
            });
            return users;
        }
    });
    kendo.bind('#main',viewModel);
  }
```

Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var viewModel = window.kendo.observable({
    userSource: [
      {id: 1, name: "user1" },
      {id: 2, name: "user2" },
      {id: 3, name: "user3" }],
    selectedTeam: function() {
      var users = [];
      $.each(this.userSource, function(idx, elem) {
        if (elem.users) users.push(elem.name);
      });
      return users;
    }
  });

  kendo.bind('#main',viewModel);

  $("#show").on("click", function() {
    alert("Selected Team: " + JSON.stringify(viewModel.selectedTeam()));
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.default.min.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<button id="show">Show</button>
<div id="main">
  <div data-bind="source: userSource" data-template="template">
  </div>
</div>

<script id="template" type="text/html">
     <div>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: users"/>#:name#
  </div>
</script>
```